# Python Pivot loses last column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I am opening a .csv with pandas naming it pull:

```
    Quarter                  Category       Value
7776   Q1-17  Autos and Transportation   6997035.2
7777   Q2-17  Autos and Transportation   7897574.5
7778   Q3-17  Autos and Transportation   6983654.1
7779   Q4-17  Autos and Transportation   7301336.9
7780   Q1-18  Autos and Transportation   7627895.3
```

There are 6 different categories and I want to structure it to be:

```
Quarter                         Q2-17       Q3-17       Q4-17       Q1-18  
Category                                                                    
Autos and Transportation   12196407.0  13591411.0  14757349.0  15735009.0   
Building and Construction   7446408.5   7873713.2   9360943.1   9355093.8   
Business and Industry       9871899.8  10264492.0   9640937.3  10668084.0   
Food and Drugs              4287428.7   4363061.2   4528251.5   4605146.4   
Fuel and Service Stations   9551811.4   8637092.7   7649205.4   7542200.1   
General Consumer Goods     18120167.0  19035865.0  19692248.0  19775445.0   
Restaurants and Hotels      8138913.7   9021774.4   9712391.4  10649011.0   
Total                      76758539.0  81455234.0  84251489.0  87868048.0
```

I tried to do this by writing:

```
reshape = pull.pivot(index='Category', columns='Quarter', values='Value')
```

It works except I lose the last column 'Q1-18'. Any idea how to keep all of the columns?

```
print(reshape.tail(4))

Quarter                         Q4-13       Q4-14       Q4-15       Q4-16  \
Category                                                                    
Fuel and Service Stations   9551811.4   8637092.7   7649205.4   7542200.1   
General Consumer Goods     18120167.0  19035865.0  19692248.0  19775445.0   
Restaurants and Hotels      8138913.7   9021774.4   9712391.4  10649011.0   
Total                      76758539.0  81455234.0  84251489.0  87868048.0   

Quarter                         Q4-17  
Category                               
Fuel and Service Stations   8395288.1  
General Consumer Goods     19794656.0  
Restaurants and Hotels     11036473.0  
Total                      93091370.0
```

Comment: can you put a print of the output?

Comment: post it as an update in your question, otherwise some heavy mental gymnastics are required :)

Comment: @GerardoFlores haha ya my bad, i'm new to this site. I just added it to my question

Comment: no worries brother we're here to help. So it looks like it's dropping your last row only, no?

Comment: The columns seem to be sorted as `Q1-16`, `Q1-17`, `Q1-18`, `Q2-16`, `Q2-17`, `Q2-18`, `Q3-16`, `Q3-17`, `Q4-16`, `Q4-17`, `...`. So did you check if `Q1-18` is after `Q1-17` in your output?

Comment: @pgngp wow yep that is it. Any idea how to have it sorted in the correct order?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out by finding a similar post.

Just need to add `order = pull['Quarter']` before the pivot.  Then after you can fix the column order by using: `reshape = reshape.reindex(columns=order)`

Comment: To be clear, no column is lost. Simply you have to reorder columns. And it should be `order=pull['Quarter'].unique()`.